# GitHub change the first pushed commit message

Tags: git, android-studio, github

As I was discovering VCS in Android Studio I pushed all files with the wrong commit message and didn't pay enough attention to that. Now I want to try to fix the message to a simple "Initial commit". How can I do this? We are talking about the very first push, and there are many pushes after it.